# Ploting points on the Chart Control

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a method that creates a series in a chart and plots 1 pair of x and y coordinates, although I am unable to add more than one pair of points / coordinates:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Set palette.
        this.chart2.Palette = ChartColorPalette.SeaGreen;

        // Set title.
        this.chart2.Titles.Add("Test Chart");

        // Add series and points
        chart2.Series.Add("RAM").Points.AddXY(22,23);
```

If I try adding something like:

```
chart2.Points.AddXY(22,23);
```

I get the following message:

> The type or namespace name 'Points' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Chart2

Comment: Have you tried chart2.Series.Points.AddXY(22,23)?  I think your answer will be something like that.

Comment: Hi, no that doesnt appear to work :(

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Points' and no extension method 'Points' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesCollection' could be found

Comment: see my edit below.  You need to refer to the series (which is a member of an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that Points is not a member of chart2.  I think you need to try:

chart2.Series["seriesname"].Points.AddXY(22,23).

Refer to this post for an example on how to add a series of points at once:

[Adding a series of points to a chart](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/59514030-45cc-426a-937e-e1dff4ede2e1)

Edit:  You need to know the seriesname which should be in your aspx page as something like this:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server"> 
  <Series> 
    <asp:Series Name="Series1">
    </asp:Series>
  </Series>
  <ChartAreas> 
    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
    </asp:ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas> 
</asp:Chart>
```

series[0] may also work.

Comment: Thanks, "chart2.Series["seriesname"].Points.AddXY(22,23);" is what I needed cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a "SeriesCollection" and add that collection to the Chart Series something like below:

```
 chart2.Series.Add(<SeriesCollection>);
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Hi, I only need one series, > that has multiple points (coordinates)

Comment: I think you can add only one series to the series collection and add any number of points to that series, which might do the trick.